# Proof : $ P' \cap N(P) = P' \cap P $, P' and P are Sylow-P sub-groups and N(P) is the normaliser of P

Tags: group-theory

I am recently studying modern algebra and came across this question in my textbook. This conclusion was used directly without any proof. I just wonder why it is true.

I first searched math.stackexchange for something related to intersections of two Sylow-P subgroups and didn't get any strong statements.

Here's the question:

Proof : $ P' \cap N(P) = P' \cap P $, P' and P are Sylow-P sub-groups and N(P) is the normaliser of P.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You will garner more responses by clicking edit, and then turning this into an actual question. Add some perspective and thoughts on your question. Usually the questions that demonstrate research effort get the greatest response. Most new users find [how to ask](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to be quite useful.

Comment: @J.W.Perry Thanks! And I am sorry about my previous statements of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just comes from the following fact:

> > **Theorem:** Any $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$ is contained in $P$.

Indeed, we see then that $P'\cap N_G(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$, and thus $P'\cap N_G(P)\subseteq P$ so that evidently $P'\cap N_G(P)\subseteq P'\cap P$. But, since $P'\cap N_G(P)\supseteq P\cap P'$ you get the desired equality.

To prove this theorem, we merely use the fact that if $H,K\unlhd G$ and $H\leqslant N_G(K)$ then $HK\leqslant G$. From this, we see that if $Q$ is a $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$ then $PQ\leqslant G$. But,

$$|PQ|=\frac{|P||Q|}{|P\cap Q|}$$

In particular, since $|P|$ and $|Q$ are both powers of $p$, with $|P|$ being the maximal power of $p$, we must have that

$$\frac{|P||Q|}{|P\cap Q|}=|P|$$

so that $|Q|=|P\cap Q|$ and so $Q\subseteq P$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed description! XD

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If $G$ is a finite group and $H \leq G$ is a $p$-subgroup, then $H$ is contained in some Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$

**2.** $P$ is normal Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N(P)$, and thus it is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N(P)$

Using these two facts you can prove $P' \cap N(P) \subseteq P' \cap P$, and the other inclusion should not be difficult.

Comment: Thanks! Your hint is quite inspiring! I just forgot P is the only Sylow-P subgroup while working on the problem :P.